# View.LayoutTo method is not working in .NET MAUI

Tags: animation, view, maui

In my project, i have more view elements in container and I need to use LayoutTo method to move the item with animation effect. but there is no changes in UI.

```
protected virtual Task<bool> OnLayoutItem(View element, Rect rect)
{
    return element.LayoutTo(rect, 200, Easing.CubicIn);
}
```

Please share your ideas to make it work.

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me if you've encountered a bug. What type of element are you moving? And what type of layout (container: stacklayout, grid, etc.) is it within? Maybe use AbsoluteLayout as container. Are you testing by targeting Windows, or a mobile platform?

Comment: I'm using "Microsoft.Maui.Controls.View" as container and used to arrange some items (content view) inside that View. Trying to drag the items by holding , in that case, i'm facing above problem.

Comment: Neither of those is a "layout". What is the immediate parent of the views you are dragging? Also, what is answer to the question that is the last sentence of my first comment (target platform you are testing)?

Comment: Immediate parent is Microsoft.Maui.Controls.View element. and Target platform is Android.

Comment: Ok thanks. Please add to question enough xaml to see the nesting of elements, starting from the header element (contains `x:Class`) at top of xaml file. E.g. if it is a `ContentPage`, containing a `StackLayout`, which contains the `View`, then add at least this much xaml: `<ContentPage ... x:Class ... > <StackLayout> <View> <TheElementYouAreTryingToMove>`. Make sure all parents (grandparents etc) of `View` are shown, up to the top of file. If convenient, make a `github public repo` containing enough code to run and see this not work.

Comment: @Prithiv did you find any work around? I think i've encountered the same problem.  I also saw this ticket: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15439